# Как назначить числовые клавиши NumPad'а в keyPressEvent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Не знаю названия клавиши (key) (если она есть)

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_NumPad1 #как отобразить нажатие клавиш NumPad'а?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Цифры** на numpad'e имеют [такой же код](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) как и основные цифры клавиатуры.

Попробуйте, нажимая на кнопки и смотря на код.
В качестве дополнительной проверки, выводится `True` если была нажата <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> или <kbd>2</kbd>

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

        print(event, event.key(), event.key() in [Qt.Key_0, Qt.Key_1, Qt.Key_2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: При проверке оказалось что код цифр на нампаде не совпадает с обычным кодом. Например: код Key_0 = 48 а на нампаде = 16777222.
Ну так вот.. Как подключиться к кнопке имея её код?

Comment: @Ivan  `if event.key() == 16777222: print(f'event.key() == 16777222')`

Comment: @Ivan, у вас numlock включен? Если нет, то будет как раз то значение, оно относится к другой кнопке. Доказываю это: `16777222` в hex это `0x1000006` (`print(hex(16777222))`), а это же значение соответствует `Qt::Key_Insert` из https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum, что подтверждает мои слова :)

Comment: Господи... Спасибо большое! Какой позор, прошу прощения за утраченное время.

Comment: @Ivan, пожалуйста :)